# Установка vesta cp на работающем multi site сервере

Tags: ubuntu, site, vesta

Привет!
Что-то я торможу.. есть сервак VPS на нем уже работает два сайта. Решил, по просьбам новых админов, накатить vesta cp! Трабл в том, что со старта vesta просит hostname, но их 3!.. 
Вопрос: как со старта стартануть vesta для multi site, чтобы потом не прописывать все руками?

PS  хостер - океан

Answer (score 1):

Она просит hostname сервера, это не одно и то же что домены сайтов, это разные вещи. Вообще сомневаюсь, что получится безболезненно накатить весту поверх существующих сайтов, так как веста устанавливает свои версии и структуру конфигов apache nginx php, а если это исключить из установки, то и толку от весты не будет. Думаю лучший вариант накатить весту на чистую ОС и по быстрому развернуть старые сайты в рамках аккаунтов весты. 
Есть еще одна деталь, с которой сам помучался и почти нигде об этом не упоминают, что лимитирование диска не работает с файловыми системами моложе ext4, например xfs не поддерживается механизмом квотирования, который используется в vesta да и в других популярных панелях.